# How to insert multiple HTML pages as a list in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

im building a presentation app.I i want to create a list of html pages( by clicking any of the list item it shows up the html page offline).

Brief about app:
The app displays a list of presentations(these r in html & saved in cache storage) . And a sync button which will sync (to and fro) new files from the cloud

What would be the correct and the most efficient approach?

Comment: maybe you can use a iframe, you have a example?

Comment: Hi marjes, yes i considered iframe....the whole idea is to make an app which will play html files offline and there would be a sync option(im using download/upload for this). Could you help me how u would have approached this problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a page with a list of links using the ion list and ion item elements. Each item will have a link to a page detail page if a page is in the URL so you can then pull up a different page for each link.